# How to clear most significant bit in byte?

Tags: java, byte, bit

I want to parse a temperature from bytes.

The temperature consists of 2 bytes. The most significant bit of the first byte indicates if the temperature is positive or negative.

This is what I have so far:

```
public double parseTemperatureBytes(byte[] temperatureBytes) {
    // Must be divided by 10 (1 decimal)
    // First bit indicates sign (bit 1 = negative, bit 0 = positive)
    // Range [0x7FFF] : [-3276.7 … +3276.7]

    byte firstByte = temperatureBytes[0];
    int positiveOrNegative = ParseUtils.getMostSignificantBit(firstByte);
    boolean isPositive = positiveOrNegative == 0;

    String temperatureHex = ParseUtils.bytesToHex(temperatureBytes);
    int temperatureHexToInteger = Integer.parseInt(temperatureHex, 16);
    double temperature = temperatureHexToInteger / (double) 10;

    if (!isPositive) {
        temperature = -temperature;
    }

    return temperature;
}


// ParseUtils

public static int getMostSignificantBit(byte b) {
    return (b & 0xff) >> 7;
}
```

This works, but I still have to make sure I ignore the most significant bit of the first byte. It's just a flag and not part of the temperature.

Ex:
If I pass in 0xFFFF it returns -6553.5 but it should be -3276.7

How can I achieve this?

Comment: How does this value differ from an ordinary big-endian `short`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check whether the given temperature is minus, using the following code..

```
public static int getMostSignificantBit(byte b) {
    return b & 0x80;
}
```

You can use the following code to get your temperature value..

```
public static double parseTemperatureBytes(byte[] temperatureBytes) {
    int firstByte = temperatureBytes[0] & 0x7F;
    int secondByte = temperatureBytes[1] & 0xFF;
    double temperature = ((firstByte << 8) | secondByte) / 10.0;

    if (getMostSignificantBit(temperatureBytes[0]) > 0) {
        temperature = -temperature;
    }

    return temperature;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The hexadecimal value f is equivalent to the binary value 1111. 0111 is 1+2+4=7 so 0x7f becomes 01111111.

```
return b &  0x7f;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can reset most significant bit with 0x7f mask, then construct 2-byte value using binary shift and bitwise or.

```
int high = temperatureBytes[0] & 0x7f;
int low = temperatureBytes[1];
int value = (high << 8) | low;
double temperature = value / 10.0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Subtract off the magnitude of the MSB. If that bit is set your number will be at least 32768. Therefore subtract that amount.

if (num > 3276.8) num = num - 3276.8;